# Atomを起動すると Unexpected end of input というエラーが表示される

Tags: atom-editor

このサイトから、atomのzipをダウンロードし、アプリを開きました。
https://atom.io/

するといきなりコンソール画面が開き、Syntax errorがあると怒られます（[スクリーンショット](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9RXK.png)）。

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at FileSystemBlobStore.load (/Users/Shige/Desktop/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/file-system-blob-store.js:36:31)
    at Function.load (/Users/Shige/Desktop/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/file-system-blob-store.js:13:14)
    at window.onload (file:///Users/Shige/Desktop/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/static/index.js:18:39)
```

ちなみに、Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/というディレクトリはなさそうです。。
もし、何か心当たり等がございましたら是非コメント下さいm(_ _)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

おそらくこのIssueと同じ現象だと思います。

[SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input · Issue #10015 · atom/atom · GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/10015)

`~/.atom/blob-store/` 以下のファイルが壊れているときにそのようなエラーになるようで、[当該フォルダを削除したら改善したという報告](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/10015#issuecomment-163958439)が挙がっています。が、それでも改善しないという報告もあります。

結局 [blob-store の読み込みに失敗したら自動で作り直す](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/10293)ことにしたようですが、このプルリクエストは現時点ではマージされていないので、もうしばらく時間がかかりそうです。

この問題は1.3.0になってから報告されているので、とりあえずは1.2.4にダウングレードすることでも回避できるかもしれません。

[Release 1.2.4 · atom/atom · GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.2.4)

Comment: ありあがとうございます！解決しました！